# Connection between "wiseguy" and the Cantonese slang 古惑仔

Tags: etymology, chinese

"Wiseguy" can mean a made man in the mafia or a smart ass who acts like they are smarter than others. What I find interesting is that the Cantonese/Chinese slang term 古惑仔 (Gu Wac Zai) has basically the same dual meaning. In this case, it's someone in the Chinese triad, or a mischievous/cunning person.

Pure coincidence? Or does anyone know if there's a connection between the two slang words?

Comment: It would be useful if you told us when 古惑仔(Gu Wac Zai) was first recorded and under which meaning, and then tell us when the second meaning was first recorded. We could them compare that with the development of "wiseguy."

Comment: An interesting question, but cross-language questions may be more suited to [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: [This summarises the etymology of "wiseguy"](https://grammarist.com/idiom/wise-guy-and-wiseguy/) but no mention of Cantonese. The only way of proving it doesn't have a Chinese influence would be to show that the US meanings both predate the Cantonese, but you'll probably need Chinese-language (or at least much more specialised) sources for the origin of 古惑仔